# Delete a file with unlink() once the file is readed

Tags: php

I want to unlink a file once the readfile() is finished

```
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
$wordText = utf8_encode($_REQUEST['TEXT']);

$section->addText($wordText);

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
//$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
$name = microtime();
$path = 'tmp/Services.docx';

$objWriter->save($path);
$essai = 'php/'.$path;

echo $essai;
readfile($objWriter);

unlink($path);
exit;
```

The point is the file is unlinked before it's read ! I mean that when I launch my download I have a beautiful **404 not found**. If I remove the unlink my download is working fine

Here is what I do in javascript side, it's ExtJs :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'php/treeWord.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {
                        'TEXT' : arrString
                    },
                    success : function(r){
                        var javaScriptVar = r.responseText;
                        alert (javaScriptVar);
                        window.open(javaScriptVar);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: That is simply not possible, unless you are referring to some other code. Speaking of which, this snippet does not look like it offers a download, so what are you referring to exactly?

Comment: @Jon I put my entire php code. My download is done in javascript, I catch the echo (i.e responseText) and then I download it with a window.open. Can you explain why you said it's not possible to unlink the file please?

Comment: "Not possible" refers to `unlink` happening before `readfile`. Once `readfile` has returned what you do with the file should not matter. I have no idea what you mean that you download with a window.open, but it sounds somewhat suspicious.

Comment: @Jon I put  my javascript code. I send the text (with var arrString) I want to put in a word doc, in the php I use the library PHPWord in order to make the Word doc, then I catch the echo response to open the file which is the path to the file (http://myfolder/tmp/Services.docx) and it is working, a pop-up is opened and in this pop-up my file is downloaded